# Apache2 Error when restarting

Tags: apache2, python, cgi

when i restart my apache2 i got this error's message

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

i insert this code to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /var/www/test>
            Options +ExecCGI
            DirectoryIndex index.py
    </Directory>
    AddHandler cgi-script .py

    ...

    DocumentRoot /var/www/test

    ...
```

when i erase the code, my apache can restart normally, but i need this code to run cgi on my ubuntu 16.04

i follow this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-apache-mysql-and-python-lamp-server-without-frameworks-on-ubuntu-14-04

please help.

Comment: it's not working

Comment: Would you mind elaborating exactly what's not working? What error message are you getting? Did you try `systemctl status apache2.service` and `journalctl -xe` as you were instructed?

Comment: it's solved, i just forget to close the virtual host

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED! foget to close , so here the correct code

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
<Directory /var/www/test>
        Options +ExecCGI
        DirectoryIndex index.py
</Directory>
AddHandler cgi-script .py

...

DocumentRoot /var/www/test

</VirtualHost>
```

and it's worked.